# How to mock Dagger activity object graphs?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, dagger

I'm using Dagger in an android app to provide application and activity scope graphs.  And I'm using Robolectric for unit-testing.  I know that I can provide Robolectric with a substitute Application class that is configured with an application object graph that overrides the real one with mocks.  But I'm stumped as to how to do the same with the activity object graphs since the standard pattern for activity object graphs is for the activities themselves to instantiate the activity-specific Dagger module they need.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need dagger if activity handles own dependencies?

Comment: You can make method `getModule()` available for overriding and in tests have activity class that extends yours but provides module specific for your tests

Comment: @EugenMartynov To your first question: according to the Dagger recommended pattern for activity-scoped object graphs ([example](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs)) each activity is responsible for using Dagger to create an object graph from a module.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Your suggestion to extend the Activity class and override `getModule` had occurred to me, but I wondered if that wouldn't be a "bad" thing to do, with respect to test design.  It's not something I've seen done in other contexts.  But I'm tempted, since it would be the simplest solution.  What do you think about that?

Comment: Is subclassing the class under test, in order to test it, acceptable?

Comment: Sorry for long delay, as for me I prefer cleaner solution. But for Android it is hard achievable sometimes since we don't have full control for activity lifecycle. I would start with this to make things working.

Comment: Hi Julian, have you managed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look to my project - https://github.com/emartynov/UrlSetter

You will find how I managed to use mocks with `Dagger` in `Robolectric` tests