# Dagger modules for Application classes that have an inheritance relationship

Tags: android, module, dagger

I'm using Dagger for dependency injection in an Android application.

I have 2 application classes, let's call them A and B.  B extends A extends `android.app.Application`

A has responsibilities and dependencies generic to any application.  B has responsibilities and dependencies specific to the current application.

I'd like to be able to have 2 modules, `AModule` and `BModule`, with A injecting itself using the former and B the latter.

The problem is that it seems as if `BModule` must have a reference to A's class at compile-time, otherwise a runtime error is thrown.  So this is what `BModule` has to look like to avoid the error (note the `injects` annotation field's value):

```
@Module(injects = {A.class}, library = true, complete = false)
public class BModule {
   ... 
}
```

But I would rather `BModule` only know about B, like this:

```
@Module(injects = {B.class}, library = true, complete = false)
public class BModule {
   ... 
}
```

The error thrown when I do this says, in effect, that the instance being injected (A) isn't of a class that `BModule` is known to be responsible for injecting.

Is there a way to achieve this that doesn't produce the runtime error?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can extend module B from module A. With having module A knowing about class A and module B knowing about class B. Read more about module extension since it is not java class extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use module extension:

```
  public class A {
      @Inject 
      AA a;
  }

  public class B extends A {
      @Inject 
      BB b;
  }
```

And modules:

```
  @Module ( injects = A.class )
  public class AModule {
      @Provides
      public AA getAA() {
         return new AA();
      };
  }

  @Module ( overrides = true, includes = AModule.class, injects = B.class )
  public class BModule {
      @Provides
      public BB getBB() {
         return new BB();
      };
  }
```

Comment: Perfect!  In following up on your [other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20308530/369722), I had noticed your use of "includes" in `TestUrlModule` and just spent the last few hours experimenting with it.  It was an important piece of Dagger I was missing.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I edited answer, so no needs to view my pet project!