# Dagger: Override @Provides-Method in Scoped Module

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

Let us suppose the following situation. There is a global module `AppModule`, a scoped module `ScopedModule`, a class `Main` and a class `Foo` in an application's *main* variant. Moreover, there is a *debug* variant with a module `DebugAppModule`, a module `DebugScopedModule` and a class `Bar`. Only the *debug* variant may know about `Bar`.

The *main* variant contains the following relevant code excerpts.

```java
@Module AppModule { /*..*/ }

@Module(injects=Main.class, addsTo=AppModule.class)
ScopedModule { @Provides Foo provideFoo() { return new Foo(); } }

class Main { scopedGraph = graph.plus(new ScopedModule(this)); }
class Foo { /*..*/ }

// In the entry point of the application
ObjectGraph.create(new AppModule());
```

The *debug* variant contains the following relevant code excerpts.

```java
@Module(addsTo=AppModule.class, overrides=true) DebugAppModule { /*..*/ }

@Module(injects=Main.class, addsTo=DebugAppModule.class, overrides=true)
DebugScopedModule { @Provides Foo provideFoo() { return new Bar(); } }

class Bar extends Foo { /*..*/ }

// In the entry point of the application
ObjectGraph.create(new AppModule(), new DebugAppModule());
```

My research and experimentation revealed that it is not possible to override `@Provides`-methods in scoped modules, i.e. when `plus`ing a module. See for example [How to Mock Dagger Activity Object Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308530/how-to-mock-dagger-activity-object-graphs). That is, in the *debug* variant whenever a `Foo` is injected it still would be a `Foo` and not a `Bar`. This makes sense because the class `Main` has a fixed dependency to `ScopedModule` (note the `new`).

It seems to me that there should be a way to inject scoped modules themselves – meta-injection so to say :). That is, `AppModule` could provide `ScopedModule` for `Main`. The problem is that `ScopedModule`'s constructor needs an instance of `Main` and so `AppModule` would need to retain an instance of `Main` and that would not fly (e.g. in an Android-specific context where `Main` would be an Activity).

**So what is the best alternative way to achieve the effect of overriding `@Provides`-methods when using scoped modules?**

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of Dagger, overriding @Provided methods are not permitted.

I found a good solution [here](https://gist.github.com/vaughandroid/2ac4aeb28d3e6b008fa4). Thanks to @vaughandroid

Basically, 
When you are providing your module into your component, you can override your methods.

```
MyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
.appModule(new AppModule() {
  @Override public Foo provideFoo() { 
      return new Bar(); 
  }
})
.build();
```

This has worked for me and I guess it'll work for you.